# How can I increase cluster capacity for Kylin inside Docker

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kylin

I am currently running a job on Kylin built from Docker: https://kylin.apache.org/docs30/install/kylin_docker.html

I am seeing this:

```
2022-05-16 15:55:43,519 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Queue available capacity: 0.0.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,520 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Estimate total cluster resource is ResourceInfo(6144,2147483647).
2022-05-16 15:55:43,521 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Cluster available capacity: 0.0.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,522 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Capacity actual available resource: AvailableResource(ResourceInfo(0,0),ResourceInfo(6144,2147483647)).
```

It is not an error but my job does not progress. I tried to set higher limits for spark in  kylin.properties, but:

```
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.master=yarn.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.executor.instances=3.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.driver.memoryOverhead=512M.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=3.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.executor.memory=3G.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.yarn.queue=default.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.submit.deployMode=client.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://localhost:9000/spark2_jars/*.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,562 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.driver.cores=3.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,563 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs://localhost:9000/kylin4/spark-history.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,563 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.driver.memory=512M.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,563 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,563 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.eventLog.enabled=true.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,563 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://localhost:9000/kylin4/spark-history.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,563 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Override user-defined spark conf, set spark.yarn.submit.file.replication=1.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,572 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] util.TimeZoneUtils : System timezone set to GMT+8, TimeZoneId: GMT+08:00.
2022-05-16 15:55:43,572 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Sleep for random seconds to avoid submitting too many spark job at the same time.
2022-05-16 15:56:41,471 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : stdout {"scheduler":{"schedulerInfo":{"type":"capacityScheduler","capacity":100.0,"usedCapacity":100.0,"maxCapacity":100.0,"queueName":"root","queues":{"queue":[{"type":"capacitySchedulerLeafQueueInfo","capacity":100.0,"usedCapacity":100.0,"maxCapacity":100.0,"absoluteCapacity":100.0,"absoluteMaxCapacity":100.0,"absoluteUsedCapacity":100.0,"numApplications":1,"queueName":"default","state":"RUNNING","resourcesUsed":{"memory":6144,"vCores":2},"hideReservationQueues":false,"nodeLabels":["*"],"allocatedContainers":2,"reservedContainers":0,"pendingContainers":2,"capacities":{"queueCapacitiesByPartition":[{"partitionName":"","capacity":100.0,"usedCapacity":100.0,"maxCapacity":100.0,"absoluteCapacity":100.0,"absoluteUsedCapacity":100.0,"absoluteMaxCapacity":100.0,"maxAMLimitPercentage":50.0}]},"resources":{"resourceUsagesByPartition":[{"partitionName":"","used":{"memory":6144,"vCores":2},"reserved":{"memory":0,"vCores":0},"pending":{"memory":10240,"vCores":2},"amUsed":{"memory":1024,"vCores":1},"amLimit":{"memory":3072,"vCores":1},"userAmLimit":{"memory":3072,"vCores":1}}]},"numActiveApplications":1,"numPendingApplications":0,"numContainers":2,"maxApplications":4,"maxApplicationsPerUser":4,"userLimit":100,"users":{"user":[{"username":"root","resourcesUsed":{"memory":6144,"vCores":2},"numPendingApplications":0,"numActiveApplications":1,"AMResourceUsed":{"memory":1024,"vCores":1},"userResourceLimit":{"memory":6144,"vCores":1},"resources":{"resourceUsagesByPartition":[{"partitionName":"","used":{"memory":6144,"vCores":2},"reserved":{"memory":0,"vCores":0},"pending":{"memory":0,"vCores":0},"amUsed":{"memory":1024,"vCores":1},"amLimit":{"memory":3072,"vCores":1},"userAmLimit":{"memory":0,"vCores":0}}]},"userWeight":1.0,"isActive":true}]},"userLimitFactor":1.0,"AMResourceLimit":{"memory":3072,"vCores":1},"usedAMResource":{"memory":1024,"vCores":1},"userAMResourceLimit":{"memory":3072,"vCores":1},"preemptionDisabled":true,"intraQueuePreemptionDisabled":true,"defaultPriority":0}]},"capacities":{"queueCapacitiesByPartition":[{"partitionName":"","capacity":100.0,"usedCapacity":100.0,"maxCapacity":100.0,"absoluteCapacity":100.0,"absoluteUsedCapacity":100.0,"absoluteMaxCapacity":100.0,"maxAMLimitPercentage":0.0}]},"health":{"lastrun":1652716601058,"operationsInfo":{"entry":{"key":"last-preemption","value":{"nodeId":"N/A","containerId":"N/A","queue":"N/A"}},"entry":{"key":"last-reservation","value":{"nodeId":"N/A","containerId":"N/A","queue":"N/A"}},"entry":{"key":"last-allocation","value":{"nodeId":"df93a1d49af1:32869","containerId":"container_1652447143614_0020_01_000002","queue":"root.default"}},"entry":{"key":"last-release","value":{"nodeId":"df93a1d49af1:32869","containerId":"container_1652447143614_0019_01_000001","queue":"root.default"}}},"lastRunDetails":[{"operation":"releases","count":0,"resources":{"memory":0,"vCores":0}},{"operation":"allocations","count":0,"resources":{"memory":0,"vCores":0}},{"operation":"reservations","count":0,"resources":{"memory":0,"vCores":0}}]}}}}
2022-05-16 15:56:41,471 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : stderr   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2022-05-16 15:56:41,472 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : stderr                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
2022-05-16 15:56:41,472 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : stderr 
2022-05-16 15:56:41,472 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : stderr   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2022-05-16 15:56:41,472 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : stderr 100  3011    0  3011    0     0   834k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  980k
2022-05-16 15:56:41,472 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] cluster.SchedulerInfoCmdHelper : Thread wait for executing command curl -k --negotiate -u : "http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler"
2022-05-16 15:56:41,476 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Queue available capacity: 0.0.
2022-05-16 15:56:41,476 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Estimate total cluster resource is ResourceInfo(6144,2147483647).
2022-05-16 15:56:41,477 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Cluster available capacity: 0.0.
2022-05-16 15:56:41,477 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] parser.CapacitySchedulerParser : Capacity actual available resource: AvailableResource(ResourceInfo(0,0),ResourceInfo(6144,2147483647)).
2022-05-16 15:56:41,478 WARN  [pool-1-thread-1] application.SparkApplication : Error occurred when check resource. Ignore it and try to submit this job. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Total queue resource does not meet requirement
    at org.apache.spark.utils.ResourceUtils$.checkResource(ResourceUtils.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.utils.ResourceUtils.checkResource(ResourceUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.spark.application.SparkApplication.execute(SparkApplication.java:277)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.spark.application.SparkApplication.execute(SparkApplication.java:94)
    at org.apache.spark.application.JobWorker$$anon$2.run(JobWorker.scala:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

From where do limits come? How can I increase them? My machine has 4 cores and 20 Gb of memory given to Docker

I am actually trying to do a small job, and there is nothing else running, moreover in the beginning it says:

```
2022-05-16 15:55:43,321 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] job.CubeBuildJob : The maximum number of tasks required to run the job is 3.0
2022-05-16 15:55:43,321 INFO  [pool-1-thread-1] job.CubeBuildJob : require cores: 1
```

So I do not get how am I hitting the limit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the yarn-site.xml and capacity-scheduler.xml file if you want to configure the cores and memory.

Comment: Please provide samples about how to configure the cores and memory in yarn-site.xml and capacity-scheduler.xml to make it a complete answer.